# Image that sits on two sections

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the hockey player mugshot that sits on two divs just like this --> [Link](https://www.nhl.com/player/connor-mcdavid-8478402)

Do I just nest the photo in the second div and just make the top margin negative?
I looked at the source code and it got me very confused.

Comment: That's exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You're on the right track.

The method you described is what the website it self is doing. See code bellow.

```
.player-jumbotron-vitals__headshot {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: `padding-bottom` is not necessary for this, thus shouldn't be a part of your  answer.

Comment: @Xatenev you are correct. I will fix this error. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Dominic and Xatenev, much appreciated.

Comment: @carllecat No problem, anything else about this question I can help clear up? You seem like you know a great deal so I didn't want to bog down my answer with to much info.

Comment: @DominicValenciana Worked like a charm!

Comment: @carllecat Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in sourcecode of the page you linked above, the smaller image is wrapped in div with class `player-jumbotron-vitals__headshot` which has negative margin :`margin-top:-100px;`. So it's first way to achieve it. Second way is to use a wrapper with `position:relative` which will contain the smaller image which has `position:absolute;` and `top:-100px;`.

Comment: Thanks @pixelCss, much appreciated!